# Why can't mythtv backend see my HDHomeRun tuner?

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

Ran a fresh install of Mythbuntu 12.04.1 32bit.  Went through the backend setup and was able to see my HDHomeRun Prime (HDHR3) device, scan, and detect channels.  Cannot get to live TV on frontend. Backend log seems to indicate it's not detecting my tuner, even though I configured it in the setup.

```
Sep 8 15:03:33 Dimension-8300 mythbackend[1668]: E TVRecEvent dtvmultiplex.cpp:325 (ParseTuningParams) DTVMux: ParseTuningParams -- Unknown tuner type = 0x2000
Sep 8 15:03:33 Dimension-8300 mythbackend[1668]: E TVRecEvent dtvchannel.cpp:308 (SetChannelByString) DTVChan(192.168.1.12-0): SetChannelByString(3_1): Failed to initialize multiplex options
Sep 8 15:03:33 Dimension-8300 mythbackend[1668]: E TVRecEvent tv_rec.cpp:3681 (TuningFrequency) TVRec(1): Failed to set channel to 3_1. Reverting to kState_None
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons for MythTV tuning issues are:

1. You didn't go though all the steps in mythtv-setup (specifically
   steps 2, 3, and 4). These 3 steps define the tuner, data, and then
   connect the tuner to the data. All 3 of these steps are required.
2. You set your tuner to use multiplexing (number of recordings > 1)
   and it doesn't support multiplexing. This is done in step 2 of
   MythTV setup (in the Advanced settings section I believe).

Answer (score 0):

I had *exactly* the same error messages that you have listed.  In addition, the listing display wouldn't show many HDHR-Prime cable channels, and displayed them with program-ID numbers instead of FIOS human readable channel numbers.

Based on [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2044554.html), I did the following:

- deleted all channels

  on Tuner-to-source panel, fetched channels for my HDHR Prime (has cablecard from Verizon FIOS)

  on Tuner-to-source panel, scanned channels for my old over-the-air HDHR

  on Tuner-to-source panel, fetched channels for my old over-the-air HDRR

Now the listing displays FIOS channels with the human-readable channel numbers, all listings are populated, and I can view live TV and record off of the HDHR-Prime.  The old over-the-air tuner works fine as well.  Interestingly, most of the over-the-air channels are slightly higher quality video than FIOS.

This was the smoothest Mythbuntu upgrade that I've done, and the new audio setup/testing features in mythfrontend are great. I now have 5.1 audio working for the first time.